# Add subscript in legend and assign colors to each item

Tags: r, ggplot2

Using `ggplot2` I am trying to add subscripts in the legend and do not want to use the default color but define colors for the curves myself.

I want `var1` to be colored blue and `var2` to be colored red, and use subscripts to define these variables. By using `scale_color_manual` I can define these colors to my variables.

Here's an example of what I am trying to do.

```
#..load packages 
require(ggplot2)

#...read data 
a1 = data.frame(x=seq(1,50),y=runif(50),z="var1",type="a") 
a2 = data.frame(x=seq(1,50),y=runif(50),z="var2",type="a")

b1 = data.frame(x=seq(1,50),y=runif(50),z="var1",type="b")
b2 = data.frame(x=seq(1,50),y=runif(50),z="var2",type="b")

#..merge the datasets
a = rbind(a1,a2)
b = rbind(b1,b2)

#..Now plot
ggplot()+
  geom_line(data=a,aes(x=x,y=y,color=z)) +
  geom_line(data=b,aes(x=x,y=y,color=z)) +
  theme_bw() +
  scale_color_manual(breaks=c("var1","var2"),values=c("blue","red"))+
  facet_grid(type~.)
```

[image]

This gives me plot with the color of my choice. But I want to add subscripts in the legend items and here's what I have tried

```
ggplot()+
  geom_line(data=a,aes(x=x,y=y,color=z)) +
  geom_line(data=b,aes(x=x,y=y,color=z)) +
  theme_bw() +
  scale_color_discrete(labels=c(expression(Var[1]),expression(Var[2])))+
  facet_grid(type~.)
```

But with the use of `scale_color_discrete` I am not able to control the colors for the `geom_line`, but do get the subscripts that I want in the legend.

[image]

Comment: How about `scale_color_manual(breaks=c("var1","var2"),values=c("blue","red"), labels=c(expression(Var[1]),expression(Var[2])))`?

Comment: @stefan that worked. Thanks. I tried a couple of things but this one did not cross my mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply using `scale_color_manual` instead of `scale_color_discrete` gave me the result I believe you are looking for:

[image]

```
ggplot()+
    geom_line(data=a,aes(x=x,y=y,color=z)) +
    geom_line(data=b,aes(x=x,y=y,color=z)) +
    theme_bw() +
    scale_color_manual(values=c("blue","red"), breaks=c("var1","var2"), labels=c(expression(Var[1]),expression(Var[2])))+
    facet_grid(type~.)
```

Comment: Thanks, i tried to use `values` with `scale_color_discrete` which did not work but using `labels` with `scale_color_manual` did not occur to me.